# Prevent access to a specific url in wordpress site using htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to deny access to the URL `www.example.com/EmployeeDirectory/?data=employes`. I have inserted the following code in the .htaccess file

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?.+=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The problem is when i add the following code i can't access even to `www.example.com/EmplyeeDirectory` page.

Comment: The way you've worded your question would suggest you want to deny access to that specific URL? Yet, the directive/regex you are using is very generic and would block any URL that contains a query string with any name/value pair? However, neither will that rule block the URL you say is being erroneously blocked. So, _something else_ is going on here? You need to include the full contents of your `.htaccess` file. And is that URL the only URL that should be blocked?

Comment: Why fiddle around with THE_REQUEST here, the query string contents can be accessed directly via %{QUERY_STRING}. So you can directly compare it for equality here, without the need for any "wildcards" in the pattern. And the part of applying this only to the specific path, can be handled by the RewriteRule.